# How to get the value of a button created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I have this button

```
button(type='button' id='getButton',  onclick='get()', value=classroom.id ) Class Students
```

..and I have this jQuery, which gets the div from the dynamically created page, which url is the ID of the classroom the user clicked on.

```
function get(){
  var classroomvalue = $("#getButton").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/classroom/' + classroomvalue,
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log('Get response:', JSON.stringify(data,  "", 2));
    $("#getResponse").html($(data).find('#students').html());
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    console.log('Ajax error response:', textStatus);
  });
}
```

Now, when I press on the Class Students, I do get the expected dropdown with the desired div from localhost:8080/classroom/CLASSROOM.ID within the current page, the only thing I cannot find to make it work is the following.

The classrooms are created dynamically, doesn't matter of Students Classroom I click, my code seems to get only the first classroom ID, not the one I click on.
Eg.
Classroom 1
Classroom 2

If I press Classroom 1, I get the desired result, but when I press Classroom 2, I get the same result as Classroom 1, where I should get the Classroom 2.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the generated html?  Sounds like you are potentially duplicating ids.

Comment: The generated HTML is a list of students belonging to the class, which resides under localhost/classroom/CLASSROOM.ID , which is the value I get in the button, and I use it to get the URL DIV for same page app.

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons with same ID attribute?

Comment: I do not, the only button with id="getButton" is the button that has the value=classroom.id.

Comment: " I press Classroom 1, I get the desired result, but when I press Classroom 2" means you have 2 (and more) buttons all with same ID = "getButton" so obviously only the first one will worrk because IDs are meant to be unique.

Comment: Hmm, I gotcha thank you. I thought that since the value is dynamic and changes it's enough. How should I go ahead? since there is one button since the rest are dynamically created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So multiple elements can't have the same id. An extremely basic  way to send the value of the button clicked to a common handler would be to pass it as a parameter from `onclick` code:

```
<button(type='button',
  onclick='get(this.value)'
  value="someClassroomId" )
 >
    someClassRoomId Students
 </button>
```

and pick up the classroom id value in `get` as an argument

```
 function get( classroomvalue){
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost:8080/classroom/' + classroomvalue,
   })
   .done( // etc
```

Multiple buttons for different classes can be set up in the same way without using id values.

---

*Update for jQuery*

The `this` value inside a code snippet assigned in HTML to an `onevent` attribute of an element is the element.

Following this pattern, a button onclick handler could be coded  in HTML as

```
<button(type='button',
  onclick='get( $(this))'
  value="someClassroomId" )
>
    someClassRoomId Students
 </button>
```

so that when called the `get` handler can use standard jQuery methods on its button argument:

```
 function get( button){
   let classroomvalue = button.val();
   // ... and so on
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand. How can I get the button in jQuery without the Id?

Comment: If you need full access to the button element  (why?) you could pass the button element from the event handler code. - see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method for having access to data on a click is keeping it in a closure rather than the DOM. When you construct the button you do it with a function that gives you assess to the data used to construct the button via a closure.

```js
function createButton(data) {
  let button = $(`<button>${data.label}</button>`);
  button.on('click', function() {
    $('#content').append(`<br>${data.id} was clicked.`);
    // Data is available via the closure for this function at time of click and doesn't need to be stored in the DOM.
  });
  $('#content').append(button);
}

createButton({ id: 1, label: 'Button 1' });

createButton({ id: 2, label: 'Button 2' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Changing the way you construct the dynamically created content to be done with functions will allow you to wire up the event handlers with classroom data passed into the function.